# Adding AdMob banner causes infinite GCAndroid deconstrcutor

Tags: android, garbage-collection, admob

After Admob banner loaded, LogCat console begins to show GCAndroid deconstrucor lines non-stop:
[image]
Even if i close my app it still continues.
I'm using Eclipse with targeting Andoid SDK 21, min SDK is 11. Google Play Service included as project as per AdMob guide. Play Service SDK ver 6.5.

This is just for test and simply copied from Android Developer Training guide

```
package com.example.admob;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

and layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code. You are doing something weird.

Comment: How do you "close my app"? Use the back key? The home key? Kill it via Manage Apps?

Comment: Use Back key or Home key. Didn't try to kill it explicitly.

Comment: When I kill the app through Settings/Apps Manager, GC stops. And by the way if I reinstall it but with `//adView.loadAd(adRequest);` commented, GC also stops to rattle.

Answer (score 0):

The logcat lines are Android garbage collector. It just means that the garbage collector is running regularly. Nothing to be concerned about.

I suspect that if you comment out `adView.loadAd(adRequest)` you will still see them.

Comment: That's the point! I commented `adView.loadAd(adRequest)` line and GC got lost.

Comment: Well all that means is that `loadAd()` is causing GCAndroid to start executing.

Comment: Yes, i know. Is that a normal behavior? GC begins executing right after banner has loaded.

Comment: I've never seen it before but notice that the text in the log message is misspelt 'deconstrcutor' A google search on that shows that it appears in other places for other reasons. I think it is just the bahviour on the device you are using.

Comment: Basically it looks like it has just causes the TC to fire up. You'll probably find doing other actions in your Activity do the same thing.

Comment: I've seen misspelt word `deconstrcutor` somewhere before on over the stackoverflow website. It seems to me this is permanent misprint for deconstructor Google made by chance or not. And this is not concerned on my RAZR i. I'll try some XPERIA for that...